# Word Interop (COM) Style LanguageID not working

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, styles, interop, comexception

I have various documents that have certain styles with an incorrect Style.LanguageID.
I have some code that should loop through all styles in a document and set each LanguageID to EnglishUK.

Solved:

```
        oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        If oWord IsNot Nothing Then
            oWord.Visible = False
            If oWord.Documents IsNot Nothing Then
                Try
                    oDocument = oWord.Documents.Open(strFilePath)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    iCouldntOpen += 1
                    bFailedToOpen = True
                End Try
                If Not bFailedToOpen Then
                    If oDocument IsNot Nothing Then
                        If oDocument.ReadOnly Then
                            iReadonly += 1
                        ElseIf oDocument.HasPassword Then
                            iPassword += 1
                        Else
                            For Each s As Style In oDocument.Styles
                              s.LanguageID = WdLanguageID.wdEnglishUK
                            Next

                            ' save the document
                            oDocument.Save()
                        End If

                        ' close the document
                        oDocument.Close()
                        oDocument = Nothing
                    End If
                    oWord.Quit()
                    oWord = Nothing

                    bFailedToOpen = False
                End If
            Else
                iUnknown += 1
            End If
        Else
            iUnknown += 1
        End If
```

Comment: Could you double-check, please, the error message you posted? It doesn't make sense (what's to the right of the `=`)... Also, I doubt `Style.Count` returns anything but an error; do you mean `oDocument.Styles.Count`? What does that return? Does s.NameLocal work?

Comment: Sorry, I did mean oDocument.Styles.Count. s.NameLocal does return the Style names. The error is actually "That property is not available on that object."

Comment: So, it works for some Styles but not all. Do some Styles not have a LanguageID? If so, how can you check that the property exists?

Comment: OK, I have a suspicion, but need a bit more information: Can you give me examples of style names for which it works and also for which it does not work? Reasoning: Styles can *base* on other styles and will *inherit* settings through these links. My thought is that the property is not available because it is coming from an underlying style - but this is just a guess which is difficult to confirm...

Comment: List Styles (there will probably be one called "No List") do not have a LanguageId property and you cannot assign to one. So you may at least need to test for specific wdStyleType values to avoid trying to assign to that property for those types of style.

Comment: This is correct, wdStyleTypeList is the issue. wdStyleTypeParagraph, wdStyleTypeTable and wdStyleTypeCharacter work fine. I will update my question with correct code.

Answer (score 0):

Use Style.Type to get appropriate Styles.

```
    oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    If oWord IsNot Nothing Then
        oWord.Visible = False
        If oWord.Documents IsNot Nothing Then
            Try
                oDocument = oWord.Documents.Open(strFilePath)
            Catch ex As Exception
                iCouldntOpen += 1
                bFailedToOpen = True
            End Try
            If Not bFailedToOpen Then
                If oDocument IsNot Nothing Then
                    If oDocument.ReadOnly Then
                        iReadonly += 1
                    ElseIf oDocument.HasPassword Then
                        iPassword += 1
                    Else
                        For Each s As Style In oDocument.Styles
                            Select Case s.Type
                                Case WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeCharacter, WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeParagraph, WdStyleType.wdStyleTypeTable
                                    s.NoProofing = False
                                    s.LanguageID = WdLanguageID.wdEnglishUK
                            End Select
                        Next

                        ' save the document
                        oDocument.Save()
                    End If

                    ' close the document
                    oDocument.Close()
                    oDocument = Nothing
                End If
                oWord.Quit()
                oWord = Nothing

                bFailedToOpen = False
            End If
        Else
            iUnknown += 1
        End If
    Else
        iUnknown += 1
    End If
```

Comment: Please include the code that's been added to the qeustion in this **answer**. Do not put answers in questions - that's what the Answer box is for. That will be much more helpful for others having similar problems. Mixing questions and answers is confusing. Please also rollback the question to its previous state so that it will be useful for others.

Answer (score -1):

You are creating your Word application as a late bound object.  This means you will not have access to intellisense for Word in your code.  This has implications as follows

Style is not defined.  You have no definition for what the object Style is.  Your code cannot determine that you mean a word style because of late binding.  Hence the error you are seeing.

WdLanguageID.wdEnglishUK is a Word constant which has the value 2507 (&H809) but because of late binding your code will not know this and instead you will have a value of 0.

The solution to both your problems to to correctly define Style and WdEnglishUK.

Comment: In VBA that might be true, although it is quite common to use CreateObject *and* have a reference to the Word object in the project which would mean that the wd constants would be interpreted correctly. But in VB.NET I suspect the compiler would object to WdLanguageID.wdEnglishUK unless the OP has a reference to the Word object library in their project.

Comment: @yokki.  My error.  The concept of properly qualifying objects still applies as the style object is presumed to be a Word style. i.e it would should be qualified as 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style' to match the oDocument.Styles iterator.

Comment: This does not answer the question, at best, it should be a comment...